# Losing precision by saving a BigDecimal in Play Framework

Tags: playframework, bigdecimal

I'm using Play Framework 1.2.4 with H2 in memory database.

```
public void aBigDecimalSavingTest() {
    BigDecimalEntity bde = new BigDecimalEntity();
    bde.bd= new BigDecimal("0.225");
    System.out.println(bde.bd); // print 0.225
    bde.save();

    bde = BigDecimalEntity.findById(Long.valueOf("1"));
    System.out.println(bde.bd); // print 0.23
}
```

Where does this problem come from ?
Play Framework ? Database support ? JPA Missing Annotation ? ...

Thanks!

Comment: What is in H2 the type of the corresponding column ?

Comment: In H2 Console the BigDecimal field is mapped by default to a DECIMAL(19, 2)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You might need to specify the precision on your Entity:

```
@Column(precision = 16, scale = 4)
BigDecimal bigdec;
```